# Does/Can combustion instabilities occur in SCRAM jet?

Tags: jet, stability, combustion, ramjet, scramjet

I was told that combustion occurs at Supersonic speeds in SCRAM jet. So acoustic disturbances/ pressure fluctuations can't travel into incoming jet stream. Does this avoids combustion instabilities in SCRAM jets?

Comment: SCRAMjet literally means Supersonic Combustion RAMjet, so the first part of your question is not in any doubt.

Comment: I don't understand your question. "So acoustic disturbances/pressure fluctuations can't travel into incoming jet stream." Is that a statement, a question, and what does it mean because I'm afraid it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @GdD, yes this sentence ("acoustic disturbances/pressure fluctuations can't travel into incoming jet stream") is the statement I'm making. Based upon that I have this question "Does this avoids combustion instabilities in SCRAM jets?".

Comment: @GdD: Subsonic instabilities can be caused by resonance - pressure waves affecting combustion and causing said pressure waves, amplifying them. If combustion happens in supersonic flow, there is no way for those pressure waves to travel forward, so resonance would not be possible.